# Jquery datepicker issue with format

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

When I type in the input field the string `01/01/24` it returns the date `01/01/2024` but if I type `01/01/25` it returns the date `01/01/1925`.

Is it possible to prevent this event and always return a date after the year `2000`?

The user doesn't want me to change the `dateFormat` by using `dd/mm/yy`, so I'm stuck with the format `dd/mm/y`.

Here is the js I use for creating the datepicker:

```
$('.hasDatepicker').datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: imagePrefix + "/img/calendar_1.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
    yearRange: "2000:2099",
    onSelect: function(e, d) {
        $(this).trigger("change");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the option [`shortYearCutoff`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-shortYearCutoff):

> The cutoff year for determining the century for a date (used in
>   conjunction with dateFormat 'y'). Any dates entered with a year value
>   less than or equal to the cutoff year are considered to be in the
>   current century, while those greater than it are deemed to be in the
>   previous century.

the default value is +10, you can enlarge it to a major value like +50.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/5Db32/

Comment: Want to note `shortYearCutoff` to `+85` will make it so it's always `2000's`.